# When Purging in Discord.py I get an error about giving 2 positional arguments

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am passing the `messages.channel.purge()` 1 variable that tells it how many messages to delete but when i run the command I get an error message saying it takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given, I read somewhere that its because python always passes the "self" but I don't know how to stop/incorporate the self argument into my code

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # print message content
    print(message.content)
    # if the message came from the bot ignore it
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # if the message starts with "!repeat" then say the message in chat
    if message.content.startswith("!repeat"):
        sentmessage = message.content.replace("!repeat", "")
        await message.channel.send(sentmessage)

    if "hello" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

    if message.content.startswith("!cleanup"):
        num2c = 0
        num2c = int(message.content.replace("!cleanup", ""))
        print(num2c)
        await message.channel.purge(num2c)
        cleanmessage = str("Cleared  "+str(num2c)+" Messages.")
        await message.channel.send(cleanmessage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the limit as a kwarg

```py
await message.channel.purge(limit=num2c)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
num2c = 0
List=message.content.slpit()
num2c = int(List[1])
await message.channel.purge(limit=num2c)
```

This should work.. : )